# Bypass browser check

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser, browser

I have my an account on my University Blog, its a kind of Learning Management System, but that site only allow me to access it through Internet Explorer, and my Internet Explorer got corrupted so I want to access it via Chrome or Firefox, do any one know how to bypass it? they are using ASP.Net at server side. Any help will be appreciate-able.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Firefox, there are several extensions which will let you "masquerade" it as a different browser.  The User Agent Switch extension will do this ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/ ).

Note that if the web-site does actually require the peculiarities which only Internet Explorer has, then this won't help.

Comment: thanx, what about chrome's extension ?

Comment: click the settings icon - Customize and Control / Options (wrench icon) - 
select Tools, then "Developer Tools"
-
a new panel will open up at the bottom of the window
- a gear icon in the very bottom right of this panel, this is "developer tools settings", click this

- in the settings popup, there is a Network section near the top of the right column

- There should be a checkbox labelled "Override User Agent", activate this.
- This will cause a drop-down list to appear right under the check box

- to close the developer tools, click the X icon to the right of the "search network" field

Answer (score 2):

just fake the user agent (most of the times, you use the user-agent to know which browser you use).here's a plugin for chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a spoof for the user agent string. Here is a [tool on the Chrome Web Store.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg). Change the user agent string to be Internet Explorer's.